# Buscando dados do usuário de uma session

Tags: php, mysql

Estou fazendo um site onde vários usuários poderão se logar. Fiz uma sessão para o login porém não consigo buscar os demais dados do usuário que estão no banco de dados. Como posso fazer isso?

tenho a função

```
$usuario = buscaUsuario($conexao, $_POST['email'], $_POST['senha']);

  if($usuario == null) {

    header("Location: ../index.php?login==0");
  } else {

    logaUsuario($usuario['nome']);
    header("Location: ../interno/index.php");
  }

die();
```

e também tenho:

```
function buscaUsuario($conexao, $email, $senha) {

    $query = "select * from usuarios where email='{$email}' and senha='{$senha}'";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);
    $usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
    return $usuario;
  }
```

na linha  `logaUsuario($usuario['nome']);` se eu mudo de nome para email ou qualquer outro dado do banco ele muda lá no meu **usuario_logado**.... mas não consigo multiplicar o **logaUsuario($usuario['nome']);** para preencher os dados na página de perfil do usuário

Comment: Depende de como é seu banco de dados. Edite a pergunta e adicione o código que você tentou fazer.

Comment: Depende também do que você está guardando nessa sessão.

Comment: Só uma pergunta antes de exibir o código. Eu consigo guardar todos os dados que estão no banco de dados relativo ao usuário numa sessão?

Comment: tenta postar codigo para podermos ajudar

Comment: @FrancisVagnerdaLuz Sim, mas não é o certo a fazer.

Comment: tenho a função  $usuario = buscaUsuario($conexao, $_POST['email'], $_POST['senha']);
  
  if($usuario == null) {
    
    header("Location: ../index.php?login==0");
  } else {
    
    logaUsuario($usuario['nome']);
    header("Location: ../interno/index.php");
  }

die();

Comment: `mas não consigo multiplicar o logaUsuario($usuario['nome']); para preencher os dados na página de perfil do usuário`
Multiplicar como assim ?

Comment: Qual o código da função logaUsuario? Se puder, por favor editar novamente a pergunta informando ele nos ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Edita a função logaUsuario e adicione os campos que,
// Você deseja salvar na SESSION
function logaUsuario($ID, $Nome, $Email/*, $Campo1, $Campo2, etc.. */)
{
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $ID;
    $_SESSION['user_name'] = $Nome;
    $_SESSION['user_email'] = $Email;
    // Adicione também exemplo
    // $_SESSION['Campo1'] = $Campo1;
    // $_SESSION['Campo2'] = $Campo2;
}
```

Ficaria assim sua condição

```
if($usuario == null) {
    header("Location: ../index.php?login==0");
} else {
    // Chame a função passando os parametros necessarios
    logaUsuario($usuario['id'],$usuario['nome'],$usuario['email']);
    header("Location: ../interno/index.php");
}
```

Comment: sim Wéllingthon, obrigado, fiz isso e não deu nenhuma erro. Mas como faço agora pare listar na munha pagina de perfil? Exemplo na pagina perfil.php quero colocar um  <h1>Nome do usuario</h1>,
  <p>email do usuario</p>,
  <p>id do usuario</p>, como posso fazer essa separação?

Comment: você pode fazer assim `<h1><?php echo $_SESSION['user_name']; ?></h1><p><?php echo $_SESSION['user_email']; ?></p><p><?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']; ?></p>`

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado! Obrigado mesmo, estava até perdendo o sono por isso...rs.. Como faço para dizer aqui no forum que a sua resposta que foi a correta?